# Serializing to XML ArrayList<T> in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, serialization

Is there a way to serialize `ActionResult<ArrayList>` from a controller in .net core 3, where `ArrayList` is composed of some type `T` (`Person` in this case).

It won't serialize to XML, only JSON. It complains the type `Person` is not known (even though it is, and it serializes just fine itself or as an array).

i.e. this fails serialization:

```
[HttpGet("List")]
public ActionResult<ArrayList> AllPersons() {...}
```

this works:

```
[HttpGet("List")]
public ActionResult<Person[]> AllPersons() {...}
```

So the `Person` type (`T`) can serialize just fine by itself, and `Person[]` also serializes just fine, but when an `ArrayList` (of `Person`) fails XML serialization with:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document.  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   SimpleRESTServer.Models.Person was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or
>   SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

(`Person` type is known statically, and both `Person` and `Person[]` will serialize just fine):

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Person))]
[Serializable]
public class Person ...
```

Comment: I can't comment why this particular piece of code won't run, but an ArrayList is designed in a way that all items are "objects" which I suspect is causing the issue. Is there a particular reason you can't do somethign like arrayList.Cast<Person> to atleast return an IEnumerable?

Comment: You have a class the inherits a base class.  XmlInclude(typeof(Person) : The XmlInclude belongs on the base class and the typeof is one of the inherited classes.  You need an XmlInclude above the base class for each one of the inherited classes.  You have Person above the class with the same name.  The XmlInclude must have a different value than the class it is above.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` has been [deprecated for quite a while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).  As @MindingData [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650085/serializing-to-xml-arraylistt-in-net-core-3#comment101750834_57650085), `ArrayList` isn't generic.

You should look into using `List<Person>` instead of `ArrayList`.  I haven't seen `ArrayList` used in probably about a decade--chances are most serialization frameworks aren't going to handle it gracefully, at least in part because it implements neither `IEnumerable<T>` nor `ICollection<T>`.  Migrating to newer, generic collection types will probably resolve any strange errors you encounter while dealing with older, deprecated, non-generic collection types.

You may be able to test this theory by using `object[]` instead of `Person[]` in your test case.  `ArrayList` is closer to `object[]`, whereas `List<Person>` is closer to `Person[]`.  (That being said, some serialization frameworks will handle `object[]` correctly even when they're unable to handle `ArrayList`, so this isn't a perfect test.)

Comment: List<Person> worked fine!
Actually the controller returns public ActionResult<List<Person>> AllPersons() {...}
And strangely, making this change ALSO fixed another issue I posted at the same time:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649146/has-anyone-gotten-swashbuckle-to-work-with-net-core-3-yet

Apparently, ArrayList is not well liked by quite a few things!